# Autofac and Keyed registrations - the proper behavior?

Tags: c#, autofac

The question is rather basic, I just started to use Autofac and encountered an issue where Autofac does not work as I expected it to work.
So given "that's the way it works" I would like to understand the logic behind such behavior.
Here is very basic code:

```
public interface X { }

internal class A : X { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<A>().Keyed<X>("A");
        ILifetimeScope scope = builder.Build();

        try
        {
            var instance = scope.Resolve<X>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The attempt to resolve would result in error (exception).
But why ? 
Indeed I did not asked to resolve specific Keyed , calling

```
var instance = scope.ResolveKeyed<X>("A");
```

would work and resolve as expected, as well as if I register

```
builder.RegisterType<A>().Keyed<X>("A").As<X>();
```

but why not to resolve to any if I did not asked for specific keyed ? 
I mean the logic I expected would be - it I ask for  specific - resolve to specific, if I did not ask for specific - resolve to any/last registered .

So why this behavior was selected as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services registered as a keyed service are only resolvable using that key.  If you want to resolve a service without using a key, it has to be registered without one using `.As<...>()`.  Register your components with both if you wish them to resolve using a key or by default.

To use an analogy, you can have a door with two kinds of handles: one with a lock, or one without.  If you want to open the keyed door, you need to supply the key.  The door without the lock obviously doesn't require a key.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, the question was "why" , what the logic or ideology behind this approach.

Comment: So you can have keyed services that aren't resolvable without the key, and you can also have keyed services that are resolvable without they key, its up to you to configure it that way.  `Keyed` services by definition require a key.  `As` (unkeyed) services do not.  It's that way because that's how the API is designed.  You can set your services up however you want.  We have keyed services here that we do *not* want resolvable without the key.

Comment: You see the reason I am asking is the scenario where I had 3 interfaces , registered keyed with different Keys and one without key , I wish to get all of them in IIndex<object,X> and then I get all the Named/Keyed with string registrations, BUT I do not get the registrations done without name, using something like (IIndex<object,X> x) , then x[null] or x[string.Empty] results in error (exception). The reason here is probably trivial - you in theory can have more then one non-keyed, so IIndex would not be able to resolve which one you want, but this still does not solve my problem :)

Comment: Per the documentation, `IIndex<string,X>` resolves only keyed services.  If you want an unkeyed service to resolve through an index, you must give it a key.  Services registered using only `As<T>` do not have a key at all, null or empty or otherwise.  You can register services using both `Named<T>` and `As<T>`.

Comment: Ok, I getting the picture :) Sill not what I want, but at least it's clearly defined now.

Comment: It's an opt-in sort of thing.  If you want it keyed, you have to opt-in to the keying.  Doing so doesn't automatically opt you in to an unkeyed service.  You must opt-in to that separately.  It's arguably better than an opt-out arrangement: if I register a keyed service that I do *not* want unkeyed, calling (e.g.) `.Keyed<T>("name").ButNotUnkeyed()` looks weird.  It's more natural to opt-in to all registrations.